# how to adjust openssl cert location

Tags: php, curl

when i execute this instruction

```
var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());
```

it gives me this array

```
array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(25) "C:\usr\local\ssl/cert.pem"
  ["default_cert_file_env"]=>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  ["default_cert_dir"]=>
  string(22) "C:\usr\local\ssl/certs"
  ["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  ["default_private_dir"]=>
  string(24) "C:\usr\local\ssl/private"
  ["default_default_cert_area"]=>
  string(16) "C:\usr\local\ssl"
  ["ini_cafile"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ini_capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
NULL
```

how to adjust default_cert_file and the other components here
as you see the link is totally wrong 
how to fix that

Comment: You should do this in your [php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php) file

Comment: in php.ini, I can just modify capath and cafile

Comment: As far as I can tell, those other values are configured at build-time for the OpenSSL library. There are references to setting `SSL_CERT_FILE` and `SSL_CERT_DIR` but they don't seem to be used at runtime.